# In Rails 4.0.3, how do i create devise users in a seeds.rb file or in a console when protected_attributes is enabled and when it is disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, strong-parameters, rails-console

Currently using Rails 4.0.3 and the latest version of Devise.

I am trying to automate the creation of a few users through a seeds.rb file in development and production.

I have currently added the gem 'protected_attributes' to my Gemfile to help with porting existing code from Rails 3.x to 4.x. and have used 'attr_accessible' for relevant fields for other entities in my data model.

I tried to create a Devise User through the rails console:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.3)
User.create(:email => 'raj@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: email, password, password_confirmation
```

As the warning notes, Strong Parameter Support in Rails 4 stops this. (Even though the rails console mentions this as a warning, no data is entered into the corresponding User table)

I tried this with both 'attr_accessible' on the :email, :password, :password_confirmation fields and with the specific line commented out and get a similar error.

I am able to create a devise user when i comment out 'protected_attributes' gem in my Gemfile and comment out the 'attr_accessible' line in my User model but i lose the ability to seed other entities programmatically.

Currently most posts dealing with Rails 4, Strong Parameters, Devise are geared towards creating and manipulating users through a Web Interface. Correspondingly most of the posts on creating Devise Users through code seem to focus on Rails 3 and earlier version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.